# Internet connection alert and hiding website url in Webview Android APP

Tags: android, android-webview

I am using this script for android webview app

http://karthiktechfreak.blogspot.in/2015/07/profesional-android-webview-application.html

But I want an internet connection alert if network is not available.

Please give your solution.

Thanks

Comment: Can you explain properly with your code

Comment: Hi O-mkar. I am new in this. I am using web code from here. http://karthiktechfreak.blogspot.in/2015/07/profesional-android-webview-application.html. Its working perfectly. But I want a code for checking internet. I want if Internet is not available it says Connection is not available. If internet is available it should open the website which I am using. Kindly help me. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

To check Internet connection in Webview

add network access permission to your AndroidManifest.xml file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
```

Then in `protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)` method add this

```
  ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager)this.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
     NetworkInfo activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
       if(activeNetwork!=null && activeNetwork.isConnected()){

        Toast.makeText(this,"Network is Available",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

     }else{

         Toast.makeText(this,"Network is not Available",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
      }
```

[Check video here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TpBRltaN86E)